# EmberJs ,could one action to many view?how to get list view from list item?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, javascriptmvc

1.what's the relation between  controller and action  and view?

i guess i mix something of them.

2.if i define  a 'userController' .does  it control user list view?

should  i define  a 'usersController' to show  user list?

if recommend some sample huge projects of embjs ,that would be better.

Answer (score 2):

There already is such huge demo projects: e.g [Discourse](https://github.com/discourse/discourse), or [Travis](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci)

If you want a smaller project, have a look @ [this example](https://github.com/dgeb/ember_data_example)